# Key permanently invalidated Exception after adding/removing fingerprint

Tags: android, android-fingerprint-api

When user adds new fingerprint or removes any existing fingerprint and then tries to launch the application it throws **KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException**

Here's my fingerprint code:

```
 public Boolean auth(FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback callback) {
    try {
        KeyStore store = accessKeyStore(DEFAULT_KEYSTORE);
        if (store == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Cipher cipher = accessCipher();
        if (cipher == null) {
            return null;
        }

        store.load(null);
        SecretKey key = (SecretKey) store.getKey(DEFAULT_KEY_NAME, DEFAULT_STORE_PASS.toCharArray());
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

        FingerprintManager manager = initManager();
        if (manager == null) {
            return null;
        }

        manager.authenticate(
                generateCryptoObject(cipher),
                generateCancellationSignal(),
                0,
                callback,
                null
        );

        return true;
    } catch (Throwable exc) {
        Logger.error(TAG, exc.getLocalizedMessage(), exc);
        return null;
    }
}



private Cipher accessCipher() {
    try {
        return Cipher.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/"
                + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/"
                + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        // Was not available.
        return null;
    }
}
```

Called auth method in onResume().

**Entire FingerPrintUtils class:**

`

```
public class FingerPrintUtils {

    private static final String TAG = FingerPrintUtils.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String DEFAULT_KEYSTORE = "AndroidKeyStore";
    private static final String DEFAULT_KEY_NAME = "myApplication";
    private static final String DEFAULT_STORE_PASS = "csdgh@jkbvj@";
    private static FingerPrintUtils fingerPrintUtils;

    private Boolean isCancelled;
    private CancellationSignal cancellationSignal;

    @TargetApi(23)
    public static FingerPrintUtils getInstance() {
        if (fingerPrintUtils == null) {
            fingerPrintUtils = new FingerPrintUtils();
        }
        return fingerPrintUtils;
    }

    @TargetApi(23)
    public Boolean isFingerAuthAvailable() {
        Boolean hasHarware = hasHardware();
        if (hasHarware == null || !hasHarware) {
            return false;
        }

        Boolean hasPrint = hasRegisteredPrint();
        if (hasPrint == null || !hasPrint) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @TargetApi(23)
    public Boolean hasHardware() {
        FingerprintManager manager = initManager();
        if (manager == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return manager.isHardwareDetected();
    }

    @TargetApi(23)
    public Boolean hasRegisteredPrint() {
        FingerprintManager manager = initManager();
        if (manager == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return manager.hasEnrolledFingerprints();
    }

    @TargetApi(23)
    public Boolean createKey() {
        try {
            KeyStore store = accessKeyStore(DEFAULT_KEYSTORE);
            if (store == null) {
                return null;
            }

            KeyGenerator generator = accessKeyGen(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, DEFAULT_KEYSTORE);
            if (generator == null) {
                return null;
            }

            generator.init(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                    DEFAULT_KEY_NAME,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
            )
                    .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
                            // Require the user to authenticate with a fingerprint to authorize every use
                            // of the key
                    .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
                    .build());
            generator.generateKey();
            return true;
        } catch (Throwable exc) {
            Logger.error(TAG, exc.getLocalizedMessage(), exc);
            return false;
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(23)
    public Boolean keyExist() {
        try {
            KeyStore store = accessKeyStore(DEFAULT_KEYSTORE);
            if (store == null) {
                return null;
            }

            store.load(null);
            SecretKey key = (SecretKey) store.getKey(DEFAULT_KEY_NAME, DEFAULT_STORE_PASS.toCharArray());
            if (key != null) {
                return true;
            }

        } catch (Throwable exc) {
            Logger.error(TAG, exc.getLocalizedMessage(), exc);
            return null;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @TargetApi(23)
    public Boolean auth(FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback callback) {
        try {
            KeyStore store = accessKeyStore(DEFAULT_KEYSTORE);
            if (store == null) {
                return null;
            }

            Cipher cipher = accessCipher();
            if (cipher == null) {
                return null;
            }

            store.load(null);
            SecretKey key = (SecretKey) store.getKey(DEFAULT_KEY_NAME, DEFAULT_STORE_PASS.toCharArray());
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

            FingerprintManager manager = initManager();
            if (manager == null) {
                return null;
            }

            manager.authenticate(
                    generateCryptoObject(cipher),
                    generateCancellationSignal(),
                    0,
                    callback,
                    null
            );

            return true;
        } catch (Throwable exc) {
            Logger.error(TAG, exc.getLocalizedMessage(), exc);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(23)
    public Boolean stop() {
        if (isCancelled != null && !isCancelled) {
            isCancelled = true;
            cancellationSignal.cancel();
            cancellationSignal = null;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @TargetApi(23)
    private FingerprintManager initManager() {
        Context context = BasePreferenceHelper.getCurrentContext();
        if (context == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            return null;
        }

        FingerprintManager manager = (FingerprintManager) context.getSystemService(Context.FINGERPRINT_SERVICE);
        if (manager == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return manager;
    }

    @TargetApi(23)
    private Cipher accessCipher() {
        try {
            return Cipher.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES + "/"
                    + KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC + "/"
                    + KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            // Was not available.
            return null;
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(23)
    private KeyStore accessKeyStore(String storeName) {
        try {
            return KeyStore.getInstance(storeName);
        } catch (Throwable exc) {
            // Was not available.
            return null;
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(23)
    private FingerprintManager.CryptoObject generateCryptoObject(Cipher cipher) {
        if (cipher == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cipher is required.");
        }
        return new FingerprintManager.CryptoObject(cipher);
    }

    @TargetApi(23)
    private CancellationSignal generateCancellationSignal() {
        cancellationSignal = new CancellationSignal();
        isCancelled = false;
        return cancellationSignal;
    }

    @TargetApi(23)
    private KeyGenerator accessKeyGen(String algo, String storeName) {
        try {
            return KeyGenerator.getInstance(algo, storeName);
        } catch (Throwable exc) {
            // Was not available.
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In your `FingerPrintUtils#Auth()` method, while initializing `cipher.init()`, put it into try catch block. Handle `KeyInvalidatedException` by deleting key from keystore and again create key using `createKey()` method. It will definitely work.

use below code for the same.

```
try
{
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
}
catch (KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException e)
{
    store.deleteEntry(DEFAULT_KEY_NAME);
    createKey();
    auth(callback);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Deleting an invalidated key in the 8.1 beta will cause an exception as well.

Comment: hey @Ken would you pls. let us know any alternative to this ?

Comment: I was hoping that would be fixed in the final 8.1 -- I take it this is still a problem?

Comment: actually i tired to replicate this issue but didnt find it. so asked you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to ask where is the createKey() method? From where to get this method? How to call it? I do not have any method like one

Comment: @Aytaj https://developer.android.com/codelabs/biometric-login#1 does a good job walking through biometrics

Comment: Remember, if you encrypted something using this key, then you cannot decrypt it. Because the existing one is Invalidated and the new one will not work obviously. You have to encrypt the data again using the new key.