# setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment does not throw exception with fingerprint added or removed

Tags: android, android-biometric

I would like to remove credentials if any of current fingerprints are removed or new one is added after the app setup biometric.

Creating key like:

```
private Key getKey(String KEY_ALIAS) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
  KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry secretKeyEntry = (KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry) getKeyStore().getEntry(KEY_ALIAS, null);
  if (secretKeyEntry != null) {
    return secretKeyEntry.getSecretKey();
  } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
    generator.init(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
      KEY_ALIAS,
      KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
      .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_GCM)
      .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE)
      .setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(true)
      .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(false)
      .build()
    );
    return generator.generateKey();
  } else {
    return getAESKey(KEY_ALIAS);
  }
}
```

And decrypting like:

```
private String decryptString(String stringToDecrypt, String KEY_ALIAS) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
  Log.d("biometric", "decryptString");

  byte[] encryptedData = Base64.decode(stringToDecrypt, Base64.DEFAULT);

  Cipher cipher;
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
    try {
      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getKey(KEY_ALIAS), new GCMParameterSpec(128, FIXED_IV));
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
      this.deleteCredentials();
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  } else {
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_MODE, "BC");
    try {
      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getKey(KEY_ALIAS));
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
      this.deleteCredentials();
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  byte[] decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(encryptedData);
  return new String(decryptedData, "UTF-8");
}
```

but even wrapping `cipher.init` with try and catch block does not throw any exception. I am testing on Emulator SDK 30.

```
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getKey(KEY_ALIAS), new GCMParameterSpec(128, FIXED_IV));
```

Reference: [Key permanently invalidated Exception after adding/removing fingerprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44886119/key-permanently-invalidated-exception-after-adding-removing-fingerprint)

Answer (score 1):

The flag `setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment` only applies to keys that require user authentication:

> Sets whether this key should be invalidated on biometric enrollment. **This applies only to keys which require user authentication (see setUserAuthenticationRequired(boolean))** and if no positive validity duration has been set (see setUserAuthenticationValidityDurationSeconds(int), meaning the key is valid for biometric authentication only.

Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/security/keystore/KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder#setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment(boolean)